# API 403.14 Forbidden - Not working in windows 10

Tags: c#, api, iis

I am trying to work my API on my local desktop which runs windows 10

I tried checking all the boxes in Windows Features>Internet Information Services>Application Development Features> I Check it all except CGI

but when trying to visit the API it does not work it has the error

> HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
>   The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.
>
> Most likely causes:
>   A default document is not configured for the requested URL, and directory browsing is not enabled on the server.
>
> Things you can try:
>   If you do not want to enable directory browsing, ensure that a default document is configured and that the file exists.
>   Enable directory browsing using IIS Manager.
>   Open IIS Manager.
>   In the Features view, double-click Directory Browsing.
>   On the Directory Browsing page, in the Actions pane, click Enable.
>   Verify that the configuration/system.webServer/directoryBrowse@enabled attribute is set to true in the site or application configuration file.

Upon trying a method it returns error `404 Not FOund`

Comment: Have you already done the things the error message suggests you to try?

Comment: "but when trying to visit the API", then how did you visit? What's the URL and what is the HTTP verb? 403.14 is expected for Web API, if wrong URLs or wrong verbs are used.

Comment: Are you publishing asp.net web api in your IIS server? If you are using other technology, then IIS would fail.  IIS will return 403.14 for asp.net web api when your application is not able to invoke asp.net extensionlesss handler. So first of all, please check whether you have selected the correct CLR version for application pool. Secondly, please go to IIS manager->site node->handlers mapping->check whether ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated has been installed. Finally, you should make sure your application have been published correctly via web deployment tool  and url/verb are correct.